# How can I multiply a matrix with vector and reshape it using one matrix multiplication using matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix X with size N x N,  and a vector Y with size NM x 1.   I want to multiply the matrix X with every N elements in Y and then reshape the resultant matrix Z row-wise. In other words, I first reshape the vector Y into a matrix Y_2 with size N x M . Then, get the matrix Z = X * Y_2, and finally reshape the matrix Z row-wise.

That process, I want to do it in matlab using matrices multiplications, as follows:

```
clear all; clc; clear; 

N = 4;   M = 8; 
X = randn(N,N); 
Y = randn(N*M,1); 
Z = kron(eye(M,M),X) * Y;
```

The problem, is that I don't get $Z$ similar to that process explained above. I mean the result of the way I used in Matlab code is not similar to the results of the process explained before.  how can I do it, where is it error in my other method?

Comment: `reshape` is essentially free. `kron` builds a large matrix, making the multiplication very expensive. Why would you want to do it this way?

Comment: Also, as you noticed, Stack Overflow doesn’t support LaTeX. Please [exit] your question to make it readable, raw LaTex is not exactly easy to parse. Use backticks \` to mark variable names.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I need to do it like that way because I have many operations to be done so that will be easier for me doing it in that way.

Comment: Your code example does something different from your text description. Please clarify. If you really want to do what the text says, it's very easy to literally do that with code

Comment: @LuisMendo , Yes I want to do what the text says, but using a matrix multiplication with the vector Y.  I mean I don't want to use the functions reshape.

Comment: @Sajjad Why not `reshape`? To do matrix multiplication, you need matching dimensions (mathematically, not only MATLAB). You need to reshape it, so why not use the function made specifically for that purpose?

Comment: “I have many operations to be done so that will be easier for me doing it in that way.” No, it will just take more time and memory to run. Write a function that implements the operation, that way you only need to code it once.